# Rhino mocks: Issue with IEnumerator.MoveNext() when stubbing an IEnumerable<T> interface

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, rhino-mocks

Our API has an interface inheriting from IEnumerable like this:

```
public interface IFoos : IEnumerable<IFoo>
{
    // Additional foo-collection-specific methods
}
```

I'm writing a unit test for a class that depends on IFoos. It has a method that iterates on an IFoos, like this:

```
public class Bar
{

    public IFoos Foos {get; set;}
    public void FooItUp()
    {
        foreach (IFoo foo in this.Foos)
        {
            foo.JumpAround();
        }
    }
}
```

In my unit test, I manage to stub out the dependency and return an Enumerator with Rhino Mocks like so:

```
[Test]
public void FooItUp_JumpsUpJumpsUpAndGetsDown()
{
    // Arrange
    var mocks = new MockRepository();
    var stubFoo1 = mocks.Stub<IFoo>();
    var stubFoo2 = mocks.Stub<IFoo>();
    var stubFoos = mockRepository.Stub<IFoos>().
    var fooEnumerator = new List<IFoo> { stubFoo1, stubFoo2 }.GetEnumerator();
    stubFoos.Stub(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Return(null).WhenCalled(x => x.ReturnValue = fooEnumerator);
    Bar bar = new bar();
    bar.Foos = stubFoos;

    // Act
    bar.FooItUp();

    // Assert
    ...

}
```

When I try running this test, an exception is thrown:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Previous method 'IEnumerator.MoveNext();' requires a return value or an exception to throw.
```

Looking at the IEnumerable interface, though, the only method I should have to implement or set a return value for is GetEnumerator() which I did above, right?  Why doesn't the foreach loop in Bar.FooItUp() just call MoveNext() on the List enumerator?

Comment: Major props for the names of your tests/mocks/example code. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Durrr.

I wasn't putting my stubs in replay state before acting on them.

Adding the line:

```
mocks.ReplayAll();
```

before calling bar.FooItUp() fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing:

```
stubFoos.Stub(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Return(null).WhenCalled(x => x.ReturnValue = fooEnumerator);
```

To:

```
stubFoos.Stub(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Return(fooEnumerator);
```

**Edit**: interesting info in that question you linked.

Having looked at it, try:

```
stubFoos.Stub(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Return(null).WhenCalled(x => x.ReturnValue = new List<IFoo> { stubFoo1, stubFoo2 }.GetEnumerator());
```

Comment: Alas, no go...that's what my call looked like initially, per this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391411/mocking-getenumerator-method-of-an-ienumerablet-types

Comment: Tried that as well, unfortunately--makes no difference whether I define the enumerator inline.

Comment: Assuming that you are aggregating a collection type inside the concrete instance of IFoos, does that concrete instance of IFoos allow for dependency injection of the collection type? I would do that instead of mocking.

Comment: @Rich: Unfortunately neither the class under test nor the project it's in have any concrete IFoos implementations. We have a number of similar interfaces (ICats, IDogs, IFunkyBunches) that inherit from IEnumerable<T>. The reason we want to stub is that it lets us avoid writing abstract base classes for each just to stub out the collection. The only alternative I see is implementing a test class (a la TestFoos) for each interface. This will get tedious--I'm actually going through and replacing our manual stub classes with Rhino mockery so we no longer have to maintain manual stubs.